# Why doesn't a library see it's resource outside resource directory?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, classpath

I suspect the question is not library dependent, but provide some details: logback is a logging library, which is configured by `logback.xml` file, which should be located at classpath' root.

Recently I found, that it is ignored, if located outside `resources` directory:

[image]

If I put it into `resources` directory, it is seen by the library:

[image]

**How this can be configured?**

IDE is IntelliJ, directory structure is Maven's.

Shouldn't java see no different between any parallel locations in differen classpath roots?

**UPDATE**

The following works fine in Eclipse:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`src/main/java` is not a classpath root. Maven will compile any `*.java` files found below this directory and put the compiled classes in the output directory.

Any non-class file (e.g. your `logback.xml`) below `src/main/java` will be **ignored**. But when put below `src/main/resources` it will also be copied to the output directory.

When you run the application the output directory will be a classpath root, and depending where you have put `logback.xml` it will be available or not.

Comment: How is this configured and how to configure as usual, i.e. to have non-java files being able to reside along with java files?

Comment: This is the way Maven works. If you want a different behaviour then create a IntelliJ project which does not use Maven as build tool.

Comment: I was always using Maven and have some parts of the project which still have some resources along with java files that stop working now. I need to know how configure this in Maven. I can't believe it is impossible within Maven.

Comment: See my update please. It works fine (prints file) in Eclipse.